# Why retrieving elements from CMap is not ordered

Tags: c++, dictionary, mfc

In my application, I have a CMap of CString values. After adding the elements in the Map, if I retrieve the elements in some other place, am not getting the elements in the order of insertion.Suppose I retrieve the third element, I get the fifth like that. Is it a behavior of CMap. Why this happens?

Comment: Is this MFC? Can you provide some code?

Comment: I know nothing about CMap, but that's how Maps usually work. They are either hash-based or order-based, neither of which preserves insertion order.

Comment: @Nick ya am talking about MFC collection class.

Comment: What `key` are you using when you're adding `values` to the map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You asked for "why", so here goes:

A Map provides for an efficient way to retrieve values by key. It does this by using a clever datastructure that is faster for this than a list or an array would be (where you have to search through the whole list before you know if an element is in there or not). There are trade-offs, such as increased memory usage, and the inability to do some other things (such as knowing in which order things were inserted).

There are two common ways to implement this

- a hashmap, which puts keys into buckets by hash value.
- a treemap, which arranges keys into a binary tree, according to how they are sorted

You can iterate over maps, but it will be according to how they are stored internally, either in key order (treemap) or completely unpredictable (hashmap). Your CMap seems to be a hashmap.

Either way, insertion order is not preserved. If you want that, you need an extra datastructure (such as a list).

Answer (score 3):

How about read documentation to CMap?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s897094z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

It's unordered map really. How you retrieve elements? By `GetStartPosition` and `GetNextAssoc`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d82fyybt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx read Remark here

> Remarks
>
> The iteration sequence is not predictable; therefore, the "first element in the map" has no special significance.

> CMap is a dictionary collection class that maps unique keys to values. Once you have inserted a key-value pair (element) into the map, you can efficiently retrieve or delete the pair using the key to access it. You can also iterate over all the elements in the map.